# Don't Allow Users to Remove A Specific Character from Input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make an input for phone numbers with country code. I put `+` by default, but it is removable. How can I make it unremovable, so users cannot remove `+` from input?

```js
document.getElementById("phonenumber").onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 13) return true;
  if ((charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    document.getElementById("phonenumber").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
    document.getElementById("lblphonenumber").innerHTML = "Phone number is invalid";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("phonenumber").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("lblphonenumber").innerHTML = "Phone number is valid";
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<label id="lblphonenumber" for="phonenumber" class="form-field-label">Please enter your phone number with country code</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" value="+" size="20">
```

Comment: hi, you can do with css. use :after or :before to place "+" sign. No need of javascript.

Comment: @priya_singh can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By, this way you can do.

```js
document.getElementById("phonenumber").onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if (charCode == 13) return true;
  if ((charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    document.getElementById("phonenumber").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)";
    document.getElementById("lblphonenumber").innerHTML = "Phone number is invalid";
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("phonenumber").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("lblphonenumber").innerHTML = "Phone number is valid";
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
  label {
    position: relative;
  }
  label::after {
    content: "+";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  input {
    padding-left: 12px;
  }
</style>
<label id="lblphonenumber" for="phonenumber" class="form-field-label">Please enter your phone number with country code</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" value="" size="20">
```

Comment: Just bellow `Save & exit` in the snippett editor! I'll do it for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this with CSS.

but still if you want to do this with javascript you can try something like this..

```
    $("input").keydown(function(e) {
   var pv=$(this).val();
   var field=this;
   setTimeout(function () {
    if(field.value.indexOf('+') !== 0) {
        $(field).val(pv);
    } 
}, 1);
 });
```